# Java game: How to overcome a hardware-limitation of a keyboard

Tags: java, key-bindings, keystroke

I'm working on a Java 2D game which requires a max of six keys be held down at the same time.
The game is for two players on the same keyboard, playing simultaneously.

However, all three computers I ran the program on only allow a max of three keys held at a time. They all have trouble with reacting to more than three keys being held.
It seems that pressing a new key after three are already held, either cancels some other key-holding or is ignored.

I've been told that this is a hardware issue. Most keyboards can't handle more than three keys held at a time. But a lot of games do require this, and they do not require special gaming-keyboards to run on my computer without problems.

So there has to be a solution that will make the game playable on any standard keyboard.

If there is, could you please explain to me how to code it in my program?
(I use Key Bindings).

**The game's controls:**

Player 1

- Rotate sprite and set angle of movement: **LEFT arrow**
- Rotate sprite and set angle of movement: **RIGHT arrow**
- Move forward: **UP arrow**
- Shoot missile: **ENTER key**

Player 2

- Rotate sprite and set angle of movement: **'A' key**
- Rotate sprite and set angle of movement: **'D' key**
- Move forward: **'W' key**
- Shoot missile: **'T' key**

**Relevant code:**

The `Key Bindings` part:

```
// An action for every key-press.
// Each action sets a flag indicating the key is pressed.

    leftAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){     
            keysPressed1[0] = true;
        }
    };

    rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            keysPressed1[1] = true;
        }
    };

// And so on...
// ....

// An action for every key-release.
// Each action sets a flag indicating the key was released.
// This is only necessary for some of the keys.

    leftReleased = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            keysPressed1[0] = false;
        }
    };

    rightReleased = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            keysPressed1[1] = false;
        }
    };

// And so on...
// ....

// Binding the keys to the actions.

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"),"upAction");
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"),"leftAction");
// etc...

    actionMap.put("upAction",upAction);
    actionMap.put("leftAction",leftAction);
// etc...
```

In the `Board` class. It has most of the game's code.
This part checks the flags and reacts to key presses and releases.

```
            keysPressed1 = tank1.getKeys(); // get flags-array of tank1.
            keysPressed2 = tank2.getKeys(); // get flags-array of tank2.

            if(keysPressed1[0]==true) // if LEFT is pressed.
                tank1.setAngle(tank1.getAngle()-3);

            if(keysPressed1[1]==true) // if RIGHT is pressed.
                tank1.setAngle(tank1.getAngle()+3);

            if(keysPressed1[2]==true){ // if UP is pressed.
                tank1.setDX(2 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(tank1.getAngle())));
                tank1.setDY(2 * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(tank1.getAngle())));
            }

            if(keysPressed1[2]==false){ // if UP is released.
                tank1.setDX(0);
                tank1.setDY(0);
            }

      // And the same for the second player's keys...
```

This is mostly how reacting to key-presses and key-releases works in my program. When a key is pressed or released, a flag is set. The `Board` class reades the flags every game-loop cycle and reacts accordingly.

As I said, the program doesn't react correctly to more than 3 keys held at a time, probably because of the keyboard. Is there a way to code a solution?

Help will be very appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sergi it's not. The guy in the question you posted askes how to handle more than one key press at a time, that's not exactly what I asked. I know how to handle 3 key presses at a time, but I asked how to avoid the hardware issue that causes the program to not be able to accept more than 3.

Comment: No way to avoid this through software. It's cheaper for keyboard manufacturers this way, so if you want more buttons at the same time, you'll have to buy a more expensive keyboard.

Comment: Then how come I have a game on my computer where I constantly push more than three keys at a time and it works? Plus, this game can have up to 4 players on the same keyboard, each one pushing 3 buttons at a time. And again it works fine on my computer. So there must be a software-way around the hardware limitation.

Comment: Try this keyboard tester and see how many keypresses your keyboard can detect at the same time -> http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/content/projects/KeyboardGhostingDemo.aspx

Comment: Looking at your game it looks like there will only be two continuously pressed keys (left/right/forwards * 2 players) plus periodic fire commands. Clever design (most importantly encouraging players not to press-and-hold the fire button) should enable this game to work with only very rare problems (both players firing at exactly the same time). Additionally you should be able to find sets of keys for which more than 3 can be pressed, although this may change from keyboard to keyboard

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're not experiencing ghosting? If it is ghosting, it's a hardware limitation.

Here is a tester -> http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/content/projects/KeyboardGhostingDemo.aspx

And here is a description of ghosting -> http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with this topic, but doing some research I stumbled upon LWJGL. It's a Java game library and looks pretty promising, according to your problem. [Take a look at this.](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_2_%28Input%29)